# Running a program before Windows login (Task Scheduler fails to execute)

Tags: windows, autohotkey, scheduled-tasks

I'd like to run a small *.exe written in AutoHotkey **before** the Windows user logon.

I created a scheduled task for this, but it doesn't seem to work. In the task scheduler it reads **"The last run of the task was terminated by the user. (0x41306)"**

Below is the (script) content of the program that I want to run, and the exported syntax of my scheduled task.

Thanks for ideas as to what might be causing the task to fail.

Contents of AutoHotkey program "Windows Pre-Login script.exe":

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; 2: A window's title can contain WinTitle anywhere inside it to be a match. 
SoundBeep
^+t::
Run, explorer.exe
WinWaitActive, This PC ahk_exe explorer.exe,, 5 ; wait 5 seconds max
if ErrorLevel
Exit
Sleep 1111
Send {Down}
Send {Enter}
SoundBeep
WinWaitActive, Enter YourText (D:),, 5 ; wait 5 seconds max
if ErrorLevel
Exit
Send MyText
Send {Enter}
Sleep 3333
WinClose, This PC ahk_exe explorer.exe
Exit
```

(This program/script should be started before Windows login and then wait for the User to login and press ^+t = Shift*CTRL+T)

Scheduled Task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2022-02-14T11:10:35.1009167</Date>
    <Author>BUERO-PC-WUE\DP</Author>
    <Description>Autohotkey</Description>
    <URI>\Start Autohotkey Script</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <BootTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </BootTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-2-34-5678912345-5678912345-5678912345-1234</UserId>
      <LogonType>S4U</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT1H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>"F:\Portable Programs\Autohotkey Skripts\Windows Pre-Login script.exe"</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Answer (score 0):

The task fails because before the login is done there is no graphical
display for the program to display upon, and no Windows Explorer.

I suggest writing the program using a method that can work without login
and does not require a display.

Some possibilities are:

- Batch `.bat` script
- PowerShell script
- Compiled program in any programming language.

Comment: But it is a compiled program, and it doesn't need neither Windows Explorer nor a display. It only sits there and waits for keyboard input. So why is it not executed?

Comment: It is not compiled in the sense that it just contains an AutoHotkey script that is packaged together with the AutoHotkey executable. The advantage is that this does not require AutoHotkey to be installed on the target computer, but apart from this it executes in exactly the same way. Before the login, Explorer is not usable, so you cannot use AutoHotkey with Explorer, or for doing any other graphical operation.

Comment: Okay, but this program does not do any graphical operation or anything with Explorer before login. So why is it not executed?

Comment: I see `Run, explorer.exe`.

Comment: it stops at the line ^+t:: and waits for user input